# How to handle received contacts with pyTelegramBotAPI?

Tags: python, api, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

I want to create something like feedback form in my telegram bot.

User fills in some information & at the end - sends his phone number (as contact). The Bot ought to copy the contact, append some information & forwad/send formed message to an admin.

I'm using this markup:

```
contact_btn = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
send_contact = types.KeyboardButton("Confirm", request_contact=True)
cancel = types.KeyboardButton("Cancel")
send_contact_btn.add(send_contact, cancel)
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Confirm the operation:", reply_markup=contact_btn)
```

I would like to check if this contact belongs to the sender or not & forward/send received contact by using:

```
bot.forward_message(???)
bot.send_message(???)
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

someone on the internet suggests to check if **user_id** in **from** object is equal to **user_id** in **Contact**. [Origin](https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial/docs/lesson_09/)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.